# How to re-render a component when all Image objects are loaded in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to know the width and height of my images dynamically, so I used the `Image` object and `onload` event function. After all images are loaded, my component should re-render and pass the height and width values to child component(`<PhotoGallery />`).

Here is my solution.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import PhotoGallery from "react-photo-gallery";
import Lightbox from "react-image-lightbox";
import { makeStyles, createStyles, Theme, Grid, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { PhotoSharp } from "@material-ui/icons";

type Props = {
   photoSrc: string[];
};

type PhotoGalleryImageType = {
   src: string;
   width: number;
   height: number;
};

export default function ProjectGallery(props: Props) {
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
   const images = useRef<PhotoGalleryImageType[]>([]);

   props.photoSrcSet.forEach((src) => {
      var photo = new Image();
      photo.src = src;
      photo.onload = () => {
         if (!images.current.some((v) => v.src === src)) {
            images.current.push({ src: src, width: photo.naturalWidth, height: photo.naturalHeight });
         }

         if (images.current.length === props.photoSrcSet.length) {
            setIsLoading(false);
         }
      };
   });

   if (isLoading) {
      return <div>"loading.."</div>;
   }
   return (
      <Grid container justify="center" direction="column">
         <Grid item>
            <PhotoGallery photos={images.current} />
         </Grid>
      </Grid>
   );
}
```

However, I think there should be a better way, because if there is no `if (!images.current.some((v) => v.src === src))` statement, the image src has duplicate values.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First wrap the loading part in a `useEffect()` to ensure it only fires once; otherwise it will fire every time something is updated.

Then, I'd suggest getting all unique sources first, and use that in a loop to load and check. Also, I think you need to use state instead of ref for the images:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import PhotoGallery from "react-photo-gallery";
import Lightbox from "react-image-lightbox";
import { makeStyles, createStyles, Theme, Grid, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { PhotoSharp } from "@material-ui/icons";

type Props = {
   photoSrc: string[];
};

type PhotoGalleryImageType = {
   src: string;
   width: number;
   height: number;
};

export default function ProjectGallery(props: Props) {
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
   const [images, setImages] = useState<PhotoGalleryImageType[]>([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      const sources = [...new Set(props.photoSrcSet)]; // Get unique values
      let loaded = 0; // Initialise a counter

      sources.forEach((src) => {
         var photo = new Image();
         photo.src = src;
         photo.onload = () => {
            // Add loaded image to array
            images.push({ src: src, width: photo.naturalWidth, height: photo.naturalHeight });
            // Update the state
            setImages(images);

            // Up the loaded counter and compare
            if (++loaded === sources.length) {
               setIsLoading(false);
            }
         };
      });
   }, []); // Empty dependency array to use it as a componentDidMount

   if (isLoading) {
      return <div>"loading.."</div>;
   }
   return (
      <Grid container justify="center" direction="column">
         <Grid item>
            <PhotoGallery photos={images} />
         </Grid>
      </Grid>
   );
}
```